# object properties wont display when concatenated with a string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object with a property, which i am displaying to the console.
If i type this, i can see the objects property, its displayed in the console:

```
console.log(myObject.property1);
```

If however i type either of these lines, it does not work:

```
console.log(`${myObject.property1}`);
```

or

```
console.log("property 1 is : " + myObject.property1);
```

Id appreciate it if someone could point out my mistake here and how i can cast my object as a string so the 2nd and 3rd lines will work.

thanks!

Comment: the third is the same as 1, i cant find the reason. Can you make a little demo for understand better

Comment: What's the type of `property1`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón: nope, they're not the same. `property1` is being stringified in the last one.

Comment: is the same object, and the same property @Cerbrus, what exact you tell me then

Comment: what is the property? option is - you dont have the value at the moment of printing. if you print just the property in console, it shows the reference to it, not the actual value of the moment.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"? Can you show the error message that you get?

Comment: Yea, but in the last line, you're forcing a `.toString()` on it by appending it to a string. Try this: `console.log({a:1});` and: `console.log("test: " + {a:1})`, @ÁlvaroTouzón

Comment: show code when you assign/change values of it.

Comment: ahhh, yes i understand you now. Yes you got reason @Cerbrus

Comment: You need to show us `myObject`, otherwise it's just guessing. If `property1` is an object, it should get printed as `[object Object]` in the 2nd case, unless it implements a `toString` method to act differently.

Comment: Also try `console.log(\`${JSON.stringify(myObject.property1)}\`)`